# Is there a position property for a textbox header?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the following XAML to display a labelled textbox of a page...

```
        <TextBox x:Name="header" Text="{Binding Accumulator}" Style="{StaticResource ShowHex}" Header="A: "/>
```

I would like show the header to the left of the textbox rather than above it.  I can't see a property to do this.  I would rather not make a stack panel of stack panels to accomplish this, if passible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `DockPanel`? Wrap the `TextBox`es with `DockPanel`, then you can specify the location of the header to the left by setting the property `DockPanel.Dock="left"`

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="header" Text="headershouldbeontheleft" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="content" Text"iamjustacontent"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: How is the result different or simpler than with a horizontal StackPanel?  I should think the DockPanel adds a tiny performance penalty.